# How to access metaobjects/slot-definition slots? Why slot-value can access slots of objects but not slots of metaobjects?

Tags: common-lisp, clos, mop

I'm having a problem acessing slots out of slot definitions. I can inspect class objects, see their slots definitions and even get some standard info about the slots definitions. However I can't access user-defined information about the slot definition.

I've already googled this for quite a while and ended up reading [CLOS & MOP specifications](https://clos-mop.hexstreamsoft.com/), a bit of the [Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html), about some [MOP concepts](https://franz.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/mop/concepts.html), and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884764/lisp-get-all-slot-names-from-an-class-instance) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879426/get-slot-value-of-an-object) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245105/how-do-i-access-an-unknown-instances-slot-using-a-string) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093513/how-to-see-docstrings-and-other-symbol-information-in-common-lisp-repl) StackOverflow that didn't help much. I even readed a piece of [SBCL's implementations](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/55d371f8e81673c798cb913010030d46859a5e13/src/pcl/defs.lisp), but to no avail.

From the pieces that I was able to put together, I can access many slots of a `SLOT DEFINITION` via some functions, e.g. access the `NAME` slot of the `SLOT DEFINITION` using `CLOSER-MOP:SLOT-DEFINITION-NAME` (which is certainly helpful), but I can't do so for slots that don't have one of these functions. For example, I can't access the `REFERENCES` slot which is provided by the `MITO` package when defining slots in a `DEFCLASS`.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
;;;; I'll use MITO because its classes have a funny REFERENCES slot
(quicklisp:quickload :mito)
;;;; I find CLOSER-MOP functions easier to use than
;;;; implementation-specific functions
(quicklisp:quickload :closer-mop)


;;;; Creates a few dummy classes
(defclass example ()
  ((one-slot :col-type (:varchar 50)
             :accessor one-slot-accessor))
  (:metaclass mito:dao-table-class)
  (:documentation "An example class."))

(defclass another-example ()
  ((normal-slot :col-type (:varchar 50)
                :accessor normal-slot-accessor)
   (example-reference :references (example id)
                      :reader example-reference-accessor))
  (:metaclass mito:dao-table-class)
  (:documentation "Another example class which references `EXAMPLE' class."))


;;;; Now try to see what's inside those classes
(let* ((class (find-class 'another-example))
       (slots (closer-mop:class-direct-slots class))
       (slot-i-am-interested (second slots)))
  (inspect slot-i-am-interested) ; Oh, apparently we have a REFERENCES slot
  ;; Why can't SLOT-VALUE access the REFERENCES slot?
  (slot-value slot-i-am-interested 'references))
```

Note that I am ***NOT*** accessing any database or anything similar, although I'm using `MITO` (I don't think I would get this problem if I didn't use any custom slot, like the `REFERENCES` one that `MITO` provides). It's just plain CLOS/MOP manipulation.

The usual output is something like (the exact output depends on your Common Lisp implementation):

```
user@linuxstudio:~/dev/lisp/slot-question-so$ sbcl --script example.lisp
To load "mito":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    mito
; Loading "mito"
....
To load "closer-mop":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    closer-mop
; Loading "closer-mop"


The object is a STANDARD-OBJECT of type MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS.
0. SOURCE: #S(SB-C:DEFINITION-SOURCE-LOCATION
              :NAMESTRING "/home/user/dev/lisp/slot-question-so/example.lisp"
              :INDICES 163840)
1. NAME: EXAMPLE-REFERENCE
2. INITFORM: NIL
3. INITFUNCTION: NIL
4. INITARGS: (:EXAMPLE-REFERENCE)
5. %TYPE: T
6. %DOCUMENTATION: NIL
7. %CLASS: #<MITO.DAO.TABLE:DAO-TABLE-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::ANOTHER-EXAMPLE>
8. READERS: (EXAMPLE-REFERENCE-ACCESSOR)
9. WRITERS: NIL
10. ALLOCATION: :INSTANCE
11. ALLOCATION-CLASS: NIL
12. COL-TYPE: NIL
13. REFERENCES: (EXAMPLE ID)
14. PRIMARY-KEY: NIL
15. GHOST: NIL
16. INFLATE: "unbound"
17. DEFLATE: "unbound"
> q
```

So, apparently, we do have a `REFERENCES` slot. However, after `INSPECT`, when we try to `SLOT-VALUE` the slot, we get an `SLOT-MISSING` error (showing only the first lines of the backtrace):

```
Unhandled SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                    {10005E85B3}>:
  When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot REFERENCES is
  missing from the object
  #<MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::EXAMPLE-REFERENCE>.

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005E85B3}>
0: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
          object ~S.~@:>" {1004B1B803}> #<unused argument> :QUIT T)
1: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
          object ~S.~@:>" {1004B1B803}>)
2: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
          object ~S.~@:>" {1004B1B803}>)
3: (ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
          object ~S.~@:>" "read the slot's value (slot-value)" REFERENCES #<MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::EXAMPLE-REFERENCE>)
4: ((:METHOD SLOT-MISSING (T T T T)) #<unused argument> #<MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::EXAMPLE-REFERENCE> REFERENCES SLOT-VALUE NIL) [fast-method]
5: ((LAMBDA (SB-PCL::OBJECT) :IN SB-PCL::SLOT-MISSING-INFO) #<MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::EXAMPLE-REFERENCE>)
6: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN "/home/user/dev/lisp/slot-question-so/example.lisp"))
```

So how can I access the "slot" `REFERENCES`? Is that really a slot? If no, how can I access it? Why a simple `SLOT-VALUE` doesn't work in this case?

Can you point me to some documentation about this topic to provide more information in case I want to understand more about this?

I'm using `SBCL 1.4.5.debian` as my lisp implementation, if that may be important.

Comment: Remember that slot names are symbols, so the package matters. When you write `(slot-value slot-i-am-interested 'references)`, you're looking for a slot named `CL-USER::REFERENCES`, but the slot actually seems to be named `MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::REFERENCES`.

Comment: @jkiiski Thank you! Replacing `'REFERENCES` with `'MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::REFERENCES` solved my problem. It's been a while since I read about packages in lisp, so I can't remember many of details about handling symbols and packages. If you provide your comment as an answer I would be glad to accept it. How did you know it was `MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::` and not e.g. `MITO.DAO.COLUMN::` or `MITO.DAO.TABLE::`?

Comment: @jkiiski I grepped both the error and the `inspect` output and neither mentions `MITO.CLASS.COLUMN`. It looks like a magical value, but it works. How you discovered/guessed it?

Comment: @GabrielFrancischini We can discover it in the repl with its fuzzy completion: type `mito:referen<TAB>`: not much results; try again with `mito::refere<TAB>` (double colon) and the first suggestion is `mito.class.column::references`, which sounds appropriate.

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290100/mop-acess-any-slot-definition-mitos-col-type/50290360

Comment: feel free to open an issue or to contribute to the Cookbook !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slot names are symbols, so the package matters when using `SLOT-VALUE` / `WITH-SLOTS`. In this case the references slots appears to be named by an internal symbol in the package `MITO.CLASS.COLUMN`.

The inspector doesn't show the package name (because it's rarely needed), but you can see that the slot definition is of type `MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS`, so you can use `CLOSER-MOP:CLASS-SLOTS` to find the slot definition:

```
CL-USER> (closer-mop:class-slots (find-class 'MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS))
(#<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::SOURCE>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::NAME>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::INITFORM>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::INITFUNCTION>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::INITARGS>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::%TYPE>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::%DOCUMENTATION>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::%CLASS>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::READERS>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::WRITERS>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::ALLOCATION>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION SB-PCL::ALLOCATION-CLASS>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::COL-TYPE>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::REFERENCES>   ;<-- HERE
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::PRIMARY-KEY>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::GHOST>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.DAO.COLUMN::INFLATE>
 #<SB-MOP:STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION MITO.DAO.COLUMN::DEFLATE>)
```

Alternatively you could have tried `(apropos "references")` to see all packages with such symbol interned:

```
CL-USER> (apropos "references")
REFERENCES
:HAS-EXTERNAL-REFERENCES-P (bound)
:REFERENCES (bound)
MITO.CLASS.COLUMN::REFERENCES  ;<-- HERE
MITO.CLASS.COLUMN:TABLE-COLUMN-REFERENCES (fbound)
MITO.CLASS.COLUMN:TABLE-COLUMN-REFERENCES-COLUMN (fbound)
...
```